# use viewdata.model to send db query to a view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to use viewdata.model to send a query result to a view. But the model requires a model item  of type Ienumerable.

```
private RScontextSansEDM db = new RScontextSansEDM();
ViewData.Model = (from a in db.TmembresansEDMdb
                  join b in db.dbTassociation on a.Idassociation equals b.Idassociation
                  where a.Idassociation == ListeMembre.Idassociation
                  select new { a });
return View();
```

There is an error at execution.

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery1[<>f__AnonymousType31[RSTestSansEdm.‌​Models.Tmembre]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[RSTestSansEdm.Models.Tmembre]'
```

and the model :

```
namespace RSTestSansEdm.Models
{
  public partial class Tmembre
  {

    [Key]
    public int Idmembre { get; set; }
    public string Nommembre { get; set; }
    public string Prenommembre { get; set; }
    public string Mailmembre { get; set; }
    public string SRCImage { get; set; }
    public int Idassociation { get; set; }

    //public virtual IEnumerable<Tmembre> MembreAssociation { get; set; }
  }
```

And the view :

```
@model IEnumerable<RSTestSansEdm.Models.Tmembre>
@foreach (var item in Model) {        
  <div class="divmembre">
    <div class="dphoto"><img src="~/Content/@item.SRCImage"/></div>
```

Help please :)

Comment: How are you using the ViewData.Model in your view? Show that code as well. Try .ToList() at the end of LINQ statement to force query execution. I do not suspect that is an issue though.

Comment: `code` @model IEnumerable<RSTestSansEdm.Models.Tmembre>

Comment: thanks for yours replys :) Error :   The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[<>f__AnonymousType3`1[RSTestSansEdm.Models.Tmembre]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[RSTestSansEdm.Models.Tmembre]'.

Comment: I added `.tolist()` in the end of the query             ViewData.Model = (from a in db.TmembresansEDMdb
                              join b in db.dbTassociation on a.Idassociation equals b.Idassociation
                              where a.Idassociation == ListeMembre.Idassociation
                              select new { a }).ToList();
`

Comment: ok ` ViewData.Model = (from a in db.TmembresansEDMdb
join b in db.dbTassociation on a.Idassociation equals b.Idassociation
where a.Idassociation == ListeMembre.Idassociation
select new { a }).ToList();
` and the error is The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType3`1[RSTestSansEdm.Models.Tmembre]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[RSTestSansEdm.Models.Tmembre]'.

Comment: Thankss Stephen it s ok with `select a` ant not necessary use `tolist` SBirthare

Comment: there is any tag for 'resolved' questions ?

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
select new { a });
```

is creating an anonymous object. Change it to

```
ViewData.Model = (from a in db.TmembresansEDMdb
              join b in db.dbTassociation on a.Idassociation equals b.Idassociation
              where a.Idassociation == ListeMembre.Idassociation
              select a);
```

Comment: Do you ever intend to mark this or any of the answers to your other questions that work as accepted? Best of luck getting help in the future!